# Label.Text > Label.Text Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have three Labels (Label1, Label2, and Label3) which all have numeric text values. When a button is clicked I want an If statement to check if Label1 is bigger than Label2 and if it is then I want Label3 to go up one. Here is the code I have:

`If Label1.Text > Label2.Text Then
            Label3.Text = Label3.Text + 1
        End If`

I have tested the above code with Label1.Text being 100 and Label2.text being 15, but Label3 will never increase; but when I try: 'If 100 > Label2.Text' or 'If Label1.Text > 15' Label3 will increase. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert string value to integer.

```
        Dim label1text As String
             label1text = Label1.Text
        Dim label1asNumber As Integer

        Dim label2text As String
             label2text = Label2.Text
        Dim label2asNumber As Integer

        Dim label3text As String
             label3text = Label3.Text
        Dim label3asNumber As Integer


        If IsNumeric(label1text) Then
        label1asNumber = CInt(label1text)
        Else
        label1asNumber = 0 'raise an error
        End If
        If IsNumeric(label2text) Then
        label2asNumber = CInt(label2text)
        Else
        label2asNumber = 0 'raise an error
        End If
```

Then you compare those:

```
        if label1asNumber > label2asNumber
            If IsNumeric(label3text) Then
            label3asNumber = CInt(label3text) +1

         Label3.Text = label3asNumber.ToString
            else 
          ..... 'your code
```